# Can a single argument constructor with a default value be subject to implicit type conversion

Tags: c++, type-conversion, default-value, explicit, explicit-constructor

I understand the use of the explicit keyword to avoid the implicit type conversions that can occur with a single argument constructor, or with a constructor that has multiple arguments of which only the first does not have a default value.


However, I was wondering, does a single argument constructor with a default value behave the same as one without a default value when it comes to implicit conversions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The existence of a default value does not stop the single-argument ctor from being used for implicit conversion: you do need to add `explicit` if you want to stop that.

For example...:

```
#include <iostream>

struct X {
  int i;
  X(int j=23): i(j) {}
};

void f(struct X x) {
  std::cout << x.i << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  f(15);
  return 0;
}
```

compiles and runs correctly:

```
$ g++ -Wall -pedantic a.cc
$ ./a.out
15
$
```

correctly, that is, if you *want* an `int` to become a `struct X` implicitly.  The `=23` part, i.e. the default value for the one argument to the constructor, does not block this.

Comment: After all, a single argument constructor with a default value is a "single argument constructor"...